# When inserting data, Insert statement conflicted with the Foreign Key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called **Book_details**, which has a primary key as **Bid** and now this BID is also a foreign key for other two table in the same database (I.e slend_details, Book_inventory)

When I insert data into inventory_details table, I'm getting the following error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__book_invent__Bid__1367E606". The conflict occurred in database "library_management", table "dbo.Book_details", column 'Bid'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

This is the insert statement I used:

```
insert into Book_inventory (Bid, present) values (001,1)
```

This is the create statement I used for my **book_inventory** table:

```
create table book_inventory (
    Bid varchar(50) Not null Foreign Key references Book_details(Bid),
    present bit Not null*
)
```

I have even checked the values i.e the data I am trying to enter in book_inventory table is present in the Book_details table. Still I get the error. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I think an environment in which '1' and '001' are two different things is likely to get very, very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Your insert;

```
insert into Book_inventory (Bid,present) values (001,1)
```

inserts `Bid` as an integer, which most likely means that it simplifies the value to `1` which does not exist as a `Bid`.

Quoting the value and inserting it as an actual string should work;

```
insert into Book_inventory (Bid,present) values ('001',1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot it did work @joachim Isaksson... thank for your interest... !

Comment: You should then click the green checkmark to mark this answer as correct if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 0):

column Bid is varchar and you are using it as integer. try this query

```
insert into Book_inventory (Bid, present) values ('001',1)
```